# Dependencia Circular en java

Tags: java, patrones-de-diseño, diseño-de-clases, dependencias

Me gustaría preguntar como podría resolver una dependencia circular:

Este es el diseño de clases que tengo:

Clase jugador

```
public class Jugador{

private String id;
private String name;
private PowerJugador power;


public Jugador(String id, String name, PowerJugador power) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.power= power;
}

public Jugador(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

// Suponer Setters y Getters y ToString
```

Clase Gremio

```
public class Gremio{

private String id;
private boolean abierto;
private PowerGremio power;
private Set<Jugador> miembros;


public Gremio(String id, boolean abierto,Set<Jugador> miembros, PowerGremio power) {
    this.id = id;
    this.abierto= abierto;
    this.power= power;
    this.miembros = miembros;
}

public Gremio(String id, boolean abierto) {
    this.id = id;
    this.abierto= abierto;
    this.miembros = new HashSet<>();
}

// Suponer Setters y Getters y ToString
```

Clase Power

```
public abstract class Power{

protected double currentPower;
protected boolean permanente;
protected double powerBoost;


public Power(double currentPower, boolean permanente, double powerBoost) {
    this.currentPower= currentPower;
    this.permanente= permanente;
    this.powerBoost= powerBoost;
}

// Suponer Setters y Getters y ToString
```

Clase PowerJugador

```
public class PowerJugador extends Power{

private transient Jugador jugador;

public PowerJugador(double currentPower, boolean permanente, double powerBoost, Jugador jugador) {
    super(currentPower, permanente, powerBoost);
    this.jugador = jugador;

public PowerJugador(double currentPower, boolean permanente, double powerBoost) {
    super(currentPower, permanente, powerBoost);
}

public void pederPower(){
      if(Integer.parseInt(jugador.getId()) < 100){
           this.currentPower -= 5.0D;
           System.out.println("El jugador " + jugador.getName() 
           + " ha perdido 5 de poder");
      }
}

// Suponer Setters y Getters y ToString
```

Clase PowerGremio

```
    public class PowerGremio extends Power{

private transient Gremio gremio;

public PowerGremio (double currentPower, boolean permanente, double powerBoost, Gremio gremio) {
    super(currentPower, permanente, powerBoost);
    this.jugador = gremio;

public PowerGremio (double currentPower, boolean permanente, double powerBoost) {
    super(currentPower, permanente, powerBoost);
}

@Override
public void getCurrentPower(){
      double pow = 0.0D;
      for(Jugador j : this.gremio.getMiembros()){
          pow += j.getPower().getCurrentPower();
      }
      currentPower = pow + powerBoost;
      return currentPower;
}

// Suponer Setters y Getters y ToString
```

Entonces como  podeis ver tengo una dependencia circular entre Jugador y su poder y el gremio y el poder del gremio;
Obviamente este es un diseño muy minimalista de lo que es, el poder tiene mas funcionalidades.

El problema está en que existe una dependencia del objeto Gremio y Jugador con el Poder y a la inversa.

Jugador <-> PowerJugador
Gremio <-> PowerGremio

de manera que cuando yo quiero crear un objeto Jugador tengo que hacer esto:

```
Jugador j = new Jugador("50","Pepe");
j.setPower(new PowerJugador(100,false,3,j));
// Y lo mismo para el Gremio
Gremio g = new Gremio("1",true);
g.añadirMiembro(j);
g.setPower(new PowerGremio(0,false,3,g));
```

Como podría resolver esta dependencia circular?
Esta mi diseño bien implementado o debería de replantearlo para evitarlo? En dicho caso, como puedo hacerlo de manera correcta?

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Te refieres a abstraer más las clases? `PowerJugador` no ocupa una referencia a `Jugador`, a menos que estés trabajando con `hibernate`, de otra manera no le encuentro sentido. Para que fuera más claro `PowerJugador` debe recivir un atributo de tipo `Power`. La clase `PowerJugador` la pondría directamente dentro de `Jugador` y lo mismo para `Gremio` y `PowerGremio`. Así tendrías tu clase de datos (un DTO o Entity en hibernate) para mover los valores del jugador por separado.

Comment: @Angel Te refieres a pasar el diseño de clase abstracta `Power` a una  `Power` normal donde `PowerGremio` y `PowerJugador` tengan un atributo de `Power`? En ese caso creo que tambien sería viable. El problema es que el poder de un gremio depende del poder de cada uno de sus judadores.
Una cosa que si habia pensado es hacerlo como tu dices y aplicar un patron observer para cuando un jugador se une/sale/pierde/gana poder y así actualizar el currentPower del gremio.
Esa sería también una manera. El problema es que seguiré necesitando un metodo que use el gremio o jugador para actualizarlo :S.